# How to set an objects angle to a HingeJoint2D limit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I set the angle of an Object to the limit of a HingeJoint2D? I mean something like this:

`gameObject.transform.rotation = HingeJoint2D.limits.max;`

Comment: Why? It's a physics component, you should add force to the connected object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're working in 2D, you likely want to set the object's up or right in the direction of the max/min of the hinge.

You can set the object's local `up` direction to be the same direction as the HingeJoint2D by using Quaternion.LookRotation:

```
HingeJoint2D hj; // The hinge joint in question
Transform minTransform; // Transform you want to set to point up towards min
Transform maxTransform; // Transform you want to set to point up towards max
Vector3 neutralLocalDir = Vector3.up; // neutral direction of joint. 
                                      // Value to be tuned or calculated in Start

// ...
Vector3 neutral = hj.transform.TransformDirection(neutralLocalDir);
Vector3 minDir = Quaternion.AngleAxis(hj.limits.min, Vector3.forward) * neutral;
minTransform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, minDir);

Vector3 maxDir = Quaternion.AngleAxis(hj.limits.max, Vector3.forward) * neutral;
maxTransform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, maxDir);
```

You may be able to use a constant value for neutral or if you need a dynamic value, look into calculating it in `Start`

Comment: Thank you very much :))) but I got an solution by myself now.
I just declared a Quaternion:
`Quaternion minAngle = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, HingeJoint2D.limits.min);`
and now I can set it easily to the rotation :)

Comment: @Zumotokari Glad to hear it! Consider [self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) when you have some time. it'll help people [who come here in the future with the same problem.](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Answer (score 0):

Ruzihms solution should just work fine. I another solution by just declaring the `transform.rotation.z` of a Quaternion to the HingeJoint2D limits, like in the following:

```
Quaternion minAngle = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, hinge.limits.min);
Quaternion maxAngle = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, hinge.limits.min);

transform.rotation = maxAngle; //or minAngle :)
```